# Objective C expression not understood

Tags: objective-c

I come from a C++ background and am learning Objective-C.

One expression that I've encountered is not clear for me. It is as follows:

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

What I don't understand is `"@[indexPath]"`. Why do i need `[]` and `@`?

Answer (score 3):

The method is...

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:...
```

and takes an array as the parameter (i.e. multiple index paths).

The code...

```
@[indexPath]
```

uses objective-c literals to create an array.

The equivalent in "old" code is...

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil];
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Where are the objective-c literals desribed? I tried a google search but i only get here and there some incomplete explanations.

Comment: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html here you go :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I read it but i don't understand why i need the brackets [ ] for that.

Comment: What don't you understand about it? Specifically.

Comment: It is the same as requiring parentheses when creating an if condition... `if (someCondition) {...` it is part of the syntax. `@[]` creates an `NSArray`. If you didn't have them then you would have ... `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath` and this would cause an error as it is expecting an `NSArray` and you are trying to pass in an `NSIndexPath`.

Comment: Thumbs up man. Now i begin to understand more. Step by step. Thank you very much.